# How to import lcapy library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to import `lcapy` but I can not do that through cmd (I also tried with Jupyter Notebook). The error I face is: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lcapy'`

Comment: Did you `pip install lcapy` first?

Comment: "**I cant do that through cmd**", what does that mean? You can't import it in the interactive python shell or are you running `python file.py` in the terminal and you are getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Did you do some basic research on how to install python modules, did you do `pip install`?

Comment: Yes I did @trsvchn

Answer (score 1):

Run in your shell:

```
pip install lcapy
```

Then just import it =)

For example, import all of the library content:

```py
from lcapy import *
```